# Counting data before sending to view in Laravel

Tags: laravel, controller

I have two tables, products and product_images, now I want to show product which has at least one image.

In controller I have a simple function in ProductController to fetch all the products:

```
public function products(){
    $allProducts = $this->product->paginate(15);
    return view('frontend.pages.products',compact('allProducts'));
}
```

But, I want to send the products which has at least one image of each product.

What should I do to achieve that?

**Edit:**

I have created relationship between tables, now how can I get my desired answer?

I have written this in the Controller:

```
$allProducts = $this->product->whereHas('product_images', function ($query){
        $query->where();
    })->get();
```

Comment: If you are using relations then by using `whereHas` and `count()` you can do it.

Comment: I have not used relation. Is it only possible with relations?

Comment: Can you show schema of both tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming table schema

```
product

    -id
    -name

product_image

    -id
    -product_id
    -url //any columns you needed


$product_ids = DB::table('product')
                  ->join('product_image','product_image.product_id','=','product.id')
                  ->select('product.id','roduct.name')
                  ->groupBy('product.id')
                  ->get();

$product_count = count($product_ids);
```

Comment: How can we write query to fetch products which has images? I have edited my question.

Comment: Deshmukh Your code works perfectly but can you please also add how we can get with relationship?

Comment: @Alisha Follow this link link which explains details of relationship. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent has this built in.

#### Example

```php
// Retrieve all posts that have three or more comments...
$posts = App\Post::has('comments', '>=', 3)->get();
```

#### In your case

In your case you could change the `$allProducts` line to be

```php
 $allProducts = $this->product()->has('product_image', '>=', 1)->paginate(15);
```

I didn't test the code above.

See documentation for more information on this topic.
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: The above code says: `Method App\Http\Controllers\FrontController::product does not exist.`

Comment: Oh sorry, what was the $this->product originally pointing to? You will need to reference your Eloquent model here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectRaw:

```
$products = Product::leftJoin('product_images',function ($join){
        $join->on('products.product_id','=','product_images.product_id');
    })->selectRaw("products.product_id i, count(product_images.id) c")
        ->groupBy('products.product_id')
        ->where('c','>=',3)
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Getting answer querying realtionship:**

The query will look like following:

```
$allProducts = $this->product->has('Images')->paginate(15);
```

But, make you sure you have created relation in Model like the following:

```
public function Images(){
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\ProductImages');
}
```

I have used hasMany relationship because one product can have multiple images.